# Can't figure out why my "Action" in the MVC "Controller" is not returning most current data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}

public JsonResult JsonData() {
    return Json(indexModel().Number, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private IndexModel indexModel() {
    IndexModel model = (IndexModel) Session["IndexModel"];
    if (model == null) {
        model = new IndexModel();
        Session["IndexModel"] = model;
    }
    return model;
}

public void RunNumber() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        indexModel().Number = i;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

View:

```
function NumberCounter() {
    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("JsonData", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#counter').html(data);
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 20) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
}


</script>

<div id="counter"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink("test", "RunNumber", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "NumberCounter" })
```

After clicking "test" link I'm trying to get jQuery AJAX to print new number in the div tag, it sends request to the Action ("JsonData") every second which is good! But "indexModel().Number" value that it get back is 0 while "For loop" in the "RunNumber()" method is still running and once "for loop" is done looping only then jQuery Ajax gets latest value of "indexModel().Number" and prints it. I've even tried to session the "number" in the controller - no luck.

How do I get it to print new number once the value of the number in the "indexModel().Number" has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by converting counter function in the controller to Static:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Static.Number = 0;

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult JsonData()
    {
        if (Static.Number == 0) Static.RunNumber();

        return Json(Static.Number, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}

public static class Static
{
    public static int Number { get; set; }

    public static void RunNumber()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            Number = i;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the Session object.
Try with something like this:

```
public void RunNumber() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var model = indexModel();
        model.Number = i;
        Session["IndexModel"] = model;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Same result, getting zero :(

Comment: public class IndexModel
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Your data is likely being cached.
Try adding cache: false to your ajax call.

```
function NumberCounter() {
    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("JsonData", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false, 
        success: function (data) {
            $('#counter').html(data);
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 20) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Any other suggestions, anyone?